# How to count peaks multiple times?

Tags: arduino, counting

I am opening a valve to let fluid flow. The pressure being measured here is with how much pressure the fluid is being pulled into a system. I am trying to measure the average value of only first 10 Pdiff (PMax-PMin). once the average value is calculated, the valve is closed.

And based on this average value, the valve will again open and close for 1 peak, and then for 2 peaks, and for 3 peaks and so on. I am storing the pressure value in an array and comparing the value with its before and after value, I get max and min values.

Comment: Can you provide with an example to do so using switch case

Answer (score 1):

You increment your peakcounter using `++peakcounter` but then immediately set `peakcounter=0` in the if block of `if(peakcounter==0)`

Since you reset your peakcounter, you never get to peakcounter == 2

```
if ( valstate == false && Pdelta >= average)
{
  {
      ++peakcounter;  // keeps the count of how many times the value has gone
      above average
  }
  // Checks for the number of times and then performs action
  if (peakcounter == 1) {
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
      startTime = millis();
      valstate = true;
      peakcounter = 0; //the offending line
  }
```

What you need to do the following (Note: code is not optimized. I don't fully understand what you need, but this should fix the issue you wrote about)

```
int currentMax = 0;
// your code here....

if ( valstate == false && Pdelta >= average){
  ++peakcounter;
  if(peakcounter > currentMax){


      // Checks for the number of times and then performs action
      if (peakcounter == 1) {
         digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
         startTime = millis();
         valstate = true;
         peakcounter = 0;
         currentMax++;
      }

   //the rest of your peakcount checking code here
   }
```

Comment: How do I correct the code so that I count one peak , reset it and then count for 2 peak, reset it, count for 3 peaks and so on...

Comment: I've edited the answer for you. I highly recommend you learn about functions so you can simplify your code. Functions would make your code much more readable and clean

Comment: I tried comparing the peakcounter with a variable as you suggested and it still doesnt work.    I am trying to count peaks and open a valve based on the count. First I count 1 peak, and open the valve for a certain time and close it. Then I count 2 peaks, open the valve for certain time and close it ans then count 3 peaks, etc

Comment: Sorry, forgot to increment the max (this needs to be done in each if) I added it now